# What's the maximum length of a SIM card PIN that iOS supports?

Tags: ios

I've seen conflicting information on this, so was wondering if somebody could help clarify.

Generally, whenever I've seen references to setting a SIM PIN on an iOS device, articles/instructions suggest a length of 4 digits are used - however, I've seen elsewhere that up to a maximum of 8 digits can be entered. Taking the above into account, what's the maximum length that can be used with a SIM PIN in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SIM PIN has a minimum of 4 digits and a maximum of 8 digits.

This goes for the iPhone, all iOS devices - and indeed any other standards compliant GSM cellphone.

For the latter statement, please consult this standards document:

https://www.3gpp.org/ftp/TSG_T/TSG_T/TSGT_05/Docs/PDFs/TP-99185.pdf

From page 66 and on, the PIN functionality is documented. Note that the PIN data length is 8.